# Access array's values by its key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code which shows the total sale up till the current date , but it shows in this way

```
Array ( 
       [Date] => 2014-01-25 
       [TotalSales] => 7
      )
```

Is there any way , where i can show in this way Total Sale:7 And Date:2014-01-25 ?

```
<?php


   $host = 'localhost';
   $user = 'root';
   $passwd = '';
   $database = 'p_database';
   $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("could not connect to database");

    $query = "SELECT DATE(order_time) AS Date, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalSales
    FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts
    WHERE DATE(order_time) = DATE(NOW())
    group by date;";

    mysql_select_db($database,$connect);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql` library is deprecated. Why not print out the errors?

Comment: do you know or even tried to know anything about arrays in php ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah you asked me ?

Comment: @user3234335 yes I did .

Comment: @AlirezaFallah Thanks For You're Question :) , As You See I Know About PHP But I haven't Practice It Almost For 6 Months+ So I Am Trying To Recall It Back, Do You Have Any Good Site For Tutorial's Where I Can Recall ?

Comment: @user3234335 Yes, use this [PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Comment: @user3234335 try hard :), good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `print_r` which Prints human-readable information about a variable . You can access the value by name

```
echo "TotalSale: ".$result['TotalSales'];
echo "Date: ".$result['Date'];
```

Comment: I Will :) Need To Wait 5 min :)

Comment: @user3234335 if it was the correct answer for the question you should mark it as such which will close the thread off.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
echo "Total Sale:{$result['TotalSales']}<br>";
echo "Date:{$result['Date']}<br>";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
echo "Total Sale:".$result['TotalSales']." And Date:".$result['Date'];
```

this will output as you desire `Total Sale:7 And Date:2014-01-25`